# .off() click function of DIV

Tags: jquery, events

I have a list of `php/mysql` results where I added a function click to go to an url, like this

```
<li><div id=m_1>DATA</div> <button id=bu_1></button></li> 
<li><div id=m_2>DATA</div> <button id=bu_2></button></li> 
<li><div id=m_3>DATA</div> <button id=bu_3></button></li> 
<li><div id=m_4>DATA</div> <button id=bu_4></button></li> 
<li><div id=m_9>DATA</div> <button id=bu_9></button></li> 
<li><div id=m_13>DATA</div> <button id=bu_13></button></li>
```

I need that anytime I press `button` `id=bu_n` I deactivate the sending to the url of its respective `div`. click `div` `id=m_n` go to url  `page.php?id=n`
I was trying with `on` and `off`.

```
$(this).on('click', function(){
 window.location = "http://www.google.com/?id="+n;    
});

$(this).off('click', function(){
 window.location = null;    
});
```

My problem is that the list generates dinamically the results, so is not predictable to recover the `id` of the `div` and using it in a function like this `function(id_result){}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need another selector, something like:

```
$('button').on
$('button').off
```

or add a class to each button and use it to select:

```
$('.btn').on
$('.btn').off
```

and then inside:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
   window.location = "http://www.google.com/?id="+ $(".btn" ).index(this);
});
```

but I don't know what is `window.location = null;` needed to do exactly here

https://jsfiddle.net/amrelgarhy/mt46pc3s/

Comment: Yes exactly as you did in the fiddle

Comment: well, trying this fiddle it doesnt work .https://jsfiddle.net/acuua1gx/1/

Comment: thanks you, In this case you are using `index(this)` which return a different value from the `div id`, as well after clicking the `button` the` div` to url doesn disable

Comment: try this ,added styling and references https://jsfiddle.net/egc5c8bL/3/

Comment: Idu, it is supossed to disable the function applied to the `div`, which redirect to `page?id=n`

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to add a class or use the selector, add a class disabled on click

 $('button').click(function (){
 if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
{ return false;
}

 $(this).addClass('disabled'); 
});
```

write the $(this) to console or debug , you will get all the related information

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/egc5c8bL/3/ The point is disabling the `div` besides the `button`, not the `button`